# How do you copy an array in common lisp?

Tags: arrays, functional-programming, common-lisp

I'd like to make copies of my 2D array, which feels like the nice, functional, nondestructive way of handling arrays.  What is the lispy way of doing this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*UPDATE*: Nowadays, [alexandria](https://common-lisp.net/project/alexandria/) has a `copy-array` very similar to the implementation given below.  Use that.

*OBSOLETE ANSWER*: I used the following, which I believed was better than the alexandria version at the time:

```
(defun copy-array (array &key
                   (element-type (array-element-type array))
                   (fill-pointer (and (array-has-fill-pointer-p array)
                                      (fill-pointer array)))
                   (adjustable (adjustable-array-p array)))
  "Returns an undisplaced copy of ARRAY, with same fill-pointer and
adjustability (if any) as the original, unless overridden by the keyword
arguments."
  (let* ((dimensions (array-dimensions array))
         (new-array (make-array dimensions
                                :element-type element-type
                                :adjustable adjustable
                                :fill-pointer fill-pointer)))
    (dotimes (i (array-total-size array))
      (setf (row-major-aref new-array i)
            (row-major-aref array i)))
    new-array))
```

The problem with the alexandria version was that the `adjust-array`
hack causes the result (at least on SBCL) to never be a
`simple-array`, which some other libraries (e.g. opticl) expect.  The
above version also was faster for me.

Someone else has published a very similar version in a different
library, but I forgot the names of both person and library.

Comment: Revisiting, I can announce that in the meantime, alexandria has changed its implementation to something close to the above.  I now recommend to use alexandria.

Comment: IMHO, alexandria has much more hype than substance. Whenever I need something of alexandria, such as `flatten` I find the source repo and copy and paste the function after reviewing it.

Comment: I can't relate to that.  It's just a stable and lightweight collection of generic utilities without further dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

The Common Lisp library [Alexandria](http://common-lisp.net/project/alexandria/) (installable through [quicklisp](http://www.quicklisp.org/beta/)) includes an implementation of `copy-array` for arbitrary ranks and dimensions:

```
(defun copy-array (array &key
                   (element-type (array-element-type array))
                   (fill-pointer (and (array-has-fill-pointer-p array)
                                      (fill-pointer array)))
                   (adjustable (adjustable-array-p array)))
  "Returns an undisplaced copy of ARRAY, with same fill-pointer and
adjustability (if any) as the original, unless overridden by the keyword
arguments. Performance depends on efficiency of general ADJUST-ARRAY in the
host lisp -- for most cases a special purpose copying function is likely to
perform better."
  (let ((dims (array-dimensions array)))
    ;; Dictionary entry for ADJUST-ARRAY requires adjusting a
    ;; displaced array to a non-displaced one to make a copy.
    (adjust-array
     (make-array dims
                 :element-type element-type :fill-pointer fill-pointer
                 :adjustable adjustable :displaced-to array)
     dims)))
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends how your 2D array is represented, and what flavor of Lisp are you using.

If you are using Common Lisp, then [copy-seq](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_cp_seq.htm#copy-seq) could be useful.

Comment: Clarified my question to include that I'm looking for a common lisp solution.  When I was googling for a solution, it said copy-seq is only good for copying vectors.  My 2D array was constructed with (make-array 2 2).  How else might I have done it?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do things `the nice, functional, nondestructive way`, then why do you even need to copy it?

- if you're copying it in order to update it -- then you're not doing it the functional way.
- if you're doing it the functional way -- then you don't need a copy.  You can just pass it anywhere and everywhere.

Maybe you want to transform it.  In that case, you could use one of Lisp's many pure functions, such as `mapcar` or `filter`.

Comment: I don't think that any of lisp's built-in functions will do precisely what I want, which is to create a new 2D array where I've swapped two values from the previous 2D array.  Would the preferred way of doing that still be to create something new rather than updating?  It seemed cleaner to copy and update.

Comment: Common Lisp's mapcar only works on lists, and CL doesn't seem to have a filter.  Out of curiosity, what Lisp were you thinking of?

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard: `Filter` is called `remove-if-not` in Common Lisp; it is one of several similar-purpose functions (`remove`, `remove-if`, `delete`, ...).

Comment: This answer makes little sense, IMHO: If you do it the functional way, you HAVE to copy an array and modify it - otherwise you would do MUTATION. Imagine you have a game with an array being the state of the board. A move + the old board -> new board. There is nothing "unfunctional" about this, unless you decide this is not a problem, a pure functional language can handle.