# setf seems to change both its arguments when they are given by aref

Tags: lisp

In Lisp, I've defined an array `a` and then let `b` be equal to `a`. I now want to redefine an entry of `b` to be equal to a different entry in `a`, like this:

```
(setf a (make-array '(2 2) :initial-contents '((1 2) (3 4))))
(setf b a)
(setf (aref b 0 0) (aref a 0 1))
```

So now, `b` will be `#2A((2 2) (3 4))`, which is all well and good. But what puzzles me is that `a` is *also* now `#2A((2 2) (3 4))`.

My question is this: why has applying `setf` to an entry of `b` changed `a` as well? I can get around this by introducing an intermediate variable with `(setf x (aref a 0 1))` and then applying `(setf (aref b 0 0) x)`, but this seems like a strange workaround to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `(setf b a)` in the second line does what is sometimes called a *shallow copy* in other languages.  That is, `b` does not become an independent copy of the array `a`, but rather becomes just another name for the exact same array.  As a result, when you modify `b`, you are modifying `a` as well.

If you want `b` to be a true, independent copy ("deep copy") of the array, then you'll need to allocate a new array and copy the elements of `a` into it.  One way to do this is for 1-dimensional arrays is with the [copy-seq](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/fun_copy-seq.html) function.  For fancier arrays you might also look at this [question about how to copy 2d arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912232/how-do-you-copy-an-array-in-common-lisp) which talks about some available libraries and approaches.